# How find first checked item index in a c# checkedlistbox with lambda

Tags: lambda

I need to set the `selectedIndex` of `MyCheckedListBox` to the first Checked Item index of the list and highlight it.

How to write a lambda expression to **Select Min Index of MyCheckedListBox.CheckedItems** as an alternate for using loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lambda or a loop. The [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property does exactly that.

From MSDN:

> **ListControl.SelectedIndex Property**
>   Gets or sets the lowest ordinal index of the selected items in the list.